# Generating unmanaged C++ via CodeDom

Tags: c#, c++, code-generation, codedom

I'm looking to programmatically generate unmanaged C++ code via CodeDom. It seems that the default implementation of `CppCodeProvider` is only capable of generating managed C++/CLI.

Any alternatives out there?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to use CodeDOM?  Do you have working code to generate C# and want to reuse it?  Or is that just the first code generation technique you heard about?

Answer (score 2):

That's not going to fly.  There's a rather serious impedance mismatch between the classes in the System.CodeDom, like CodeStatement et al, and the structure of a native C++ program.  There's no way to model something as basic as a non-class member function, not supported in managed code.  Or the notion of #including header files.  Or single-pass compilation.  Etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at tools from OSSNokalva. They have some interesting tools for code generation from XSD.
http://www.oss.com/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way of building native C++ built in to .NET. I've been looking for a long time. Even if you build a Visual Studio Extension, you can't generate it in the same way that you can just have string[] sources for the C# compiler.